# Angular 2 directive: How to get created echarts instance in directive?

Tags: angular, typescript, echarts

**Purpose**: I am trying to build a simple Angular 2 directive for ECharts (a chart library)

---

**Details**:

I create the charts in `ngAfterViewInit()`, and for the first time, it works, the charts do resize when window resize.

Then I click to another page, `ngOnDestroy()` runs, and charts are destroyed.

Then I click back to chart page, charts are re-created, however, this time charts won't resize when window resizes, and `console.log(chart)` returns `'undefined'` instead of echarts instance.

How can I get echarts instance again and make it resizable?

---

**All the code**:

Below is all the code of `EChartsDirective` for ECharts:

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, Input } from '@angular/core';
let echarts = require('echarts');

@Directive({ selector: '[myECharts]' })

export class EChartsDirective {
    el: ElementRef;
    constructor(el: ElementRef) {
        this.el = el;
    }

    @Input() EChartsOptions: any;
    private mychart;


    ngAfterViewInit() {
        let chart = this.mychart = echarts.init(this.el.nativeElement);

        if (!this.EChartsOptions) return;

        this.mychart.setOption(this.EChartsOptions);

        $(window).on('resize', function(){
            console.log(chart);
            chart.resize(); // <- this only works for the first time
                            // if I change to another page, then back to chart page, it will return 'undefined'
                            // the chart is still there, but won't resize on window resize any more
        })
    }

    ngOnDestroy() {
        if (this.mychart) {
            this.mychart.dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
    ngAfterViewInit() {
      this.mychart = echarts.init(this.el.nativeElement);
      if (!this.EChartsOptions) return;

      this.mychart.setOption(this.EChartsOptions);
    }

    @HostListener('window:resize)
    onResize() {
        console.log(chart);
        if(this.mychart) {
          this.mychart.resize();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi Günter, thanks for the fast response! `this.myChart.resize();` gets error: `"Property 'myChart' does not exist on type 'EChartsDirective'"`, am I missing anything?

Comment: Sounds like the first `resize` event was received before `ngAfterViewInit()`. I updated my answer (added `if(){}`

Comment: Sorry, it works! You made my day! Thank you so much ❤️  (BTW, previously, it doesn't work because there's a typo, my name is `mychart` instead of `myChart`)

Comment: You're welcome. Glad to hear your could make it work. Habits - I always use camelCase - sorry for that.

Comment: Hi Günter, my fault! I should have used camelCase. Again, thank you so much!

Answer (score 3):

Using ngx-echarts, you can do it in a more Angular friendly way, in your html:

```
<div echarts (chartInit)="onChartInit($event)" [options]="options" class="demo-chart"></div>
```

and in your component:

```
onChartInit(e: any) {
    this.chartInstance = e;
    console.log('on chart init:', e);
  }
```

Source: https://xieziyu.github.io/ngx-echarts/#/basic/basic-usage